# Show View on on top of Tab Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

This is what I am able to do currently:

UIView Element With a Button on It

[image: UIView Element With a Button on It]

This is what I want to do:

[image]

Note: The second screenshot is taken from an App running on Android

Edit: 
I did try using `parentView.bringSubviewToFront(childView)` but there was no change

Answer (score -1):

You might consider custom the UITabBar, here is an example:
http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

The problem you have now is putting the Button inside on of the viewControllers, which is under the tabBar.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11628571)

Comment: Well, I just gave a direction, the valuable part is the keywords "Custom UITabBar" .